Postfix 3.6 configuration: Turning Off Body and Header Checks for Internal Users produces warning message
I am running a postfix server (3.6) on an Ubuntu server 24.04. The mail server is running fine so far. DKIM, SPF and DMARC are active and there are no problems with Spamassassin and Amavis/Clamav.
I run header and body checks for mails and do not want to run them for local users.
After some research, I came across an article on a website where this is explained. Click here for the website.
According to this, a second (in my case a local) IP should be created as an alias for the network interface and then something should be added to the file /etc/postfix/master.cf to solve the problem. I have done this and it works so that no header/body checks are carried out for internal mails.
But now I get a warning message every minute:
postfix/master[xxxx]: warning: master_wakeup_timer_event: service pickup(public/pickup): Connection refused
I added a new line in the /etc/hosts file to create a local IP alias:
127.0.1.2 substitute.mydomain.de substitute
This is my /etc/postfix/main.cf file:
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#smtpd_tls_security_level=may

#       Enable TLS Encryption when Postfix receives incoming emails
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.de/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.de/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
# smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
# smtp_tls_security_level=may
# smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

#       Enable TLS Encryption when Postfix sends outgoing emails
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

#       Enforce TLSv1.3 or TLSv1.2

smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=0x0303
smtpd_tls_protocols = >=0x0303
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=0x0303
smtp_tls_protocols = >=0x0303

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = my.domain.de
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
message_size_limit = 52428800

mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtputf8_enable = no

virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps =
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf,
   proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
authorized_submit_users = root,www-data,vmail
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks,
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_unauth_destination,
   reject_rhsbl_sender         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dbl.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.1.[2..99],
   reject_rhsbl_helo           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dbl.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.1.[2..99],
   reject_rhsbl_reverse_client xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dbl.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.1.[2..99],
   reject_rhsbl_sender         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.zrd.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.2.[2..24],
   reject_rhsbl_helo           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.zrd.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.2.[2..24],
   reject_rhsbl_reverse_client xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.zrd.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.2.[2..24],
#   reject_rbl_client           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.zen.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.0.[2..255]
   check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
#   check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock, local:opendmarc/opendmarc.sock, local:spamass/spamass.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
   check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
   permit_mynetworks
   permit_sasl_authenticated
   reject_unknown_sender_domain
   reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
   reject_unknown_client_hostname

header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
rbl_reply_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dnsbl-reply-map
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
postscreen_blacklist_action = drop
postscreen_greet_action = enforce

postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 3
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.zen.dq.spamhaus.net=127.0.0.[2..255]
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map = texthash:/etc/postfix/dnsbl_reply

And this is my /etc/postfix/master.cf file:
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission     inet     n    -    y    -    -    smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
# Choose one: enable submission for loopback clients only, or for any client.
#127.0.0.1:submission inet n -   y       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=static:all
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#     Instead of specifying complex smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions here,
#     specify "smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions=$mua_<xxx>_restrictions"
#     here, and specify mua_<xxx>_restrictions in main.cf (where
#     "<xxx>" is "client", "helo", "sender", "relay", or "recipient").
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
# Choose one: enable submissions for loopback clients only, or for any client.
#127.0.0.1:submissions inet n  -       y       -       -       smtpd
#submissions     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submissions
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=static:all
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#     Instead of specifying complex smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions here,
#     specify "smtpd_<xxx>_restrictions=$mua_<xxx>_restrictions"
#     here, and specify mua_<xxx>_restrictions in main.cf (where
#     "<xxx>" is "client", "helo", "sender", "relay", or "recipient").
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

policyd-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
smtp-amavis unix -    -    n    -    4 smtp
    -o syslog_name=postfix/amavis
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none

127.0.0.1:10025   inet   n    -     n     -     -    smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/10025
    -o content_filter=
    -o mynetworks_style=host
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=

retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

policyd-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
smtp-amavis unix -    -    n    -    4 smtp
    -o syslog_name=postfix/amavis
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none

127.0.0.1:10025   inet   n    -     n     -     -    smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/10025
    -o content_filter=
    -o mynetworks_style=host
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings

127.0.1.2:smtp inet  n     -     n     -     -   smtpd
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
127.0.0.1:smtp      inet  n     -     n     -     -   smtpd
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
pickup              fifo  n     -     n    60     1   pickup
   -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks

I added the last six lines for switching off the header/body checks for local users.
There must be an error, but unfortunately I don't know which one. Does anyone have an idea?
Edit:
However, postfix.org states that something must also be added to main.cf. See picture!
How confusing!


After a little testing, I found that the body/header checks are still performed when I remotely deliver a mail.
If the root user sends an email internally, the body/header checks are apparently skipped.
Apparently this must be the case.
